# Wordpress Fatal error: add_rewrite_tag()

Tags: wordpress

I am using the following code to pull in posts to a page outside of wordpress(3.3.1):

```
require_once './blog/wp-load.php';
query_posts('numberposts=3');
```

When the permalinks are set to default the code works fine and the posts display. When I set the permalinks to anything other than default I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rewrite_tag() on a non-object in ...

I have searched around the only fix I can find is to rename the plugins folder but that has no effect.